# Pass primitive Type as a parameter from XAML

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, xaml

**TL;DR** - I'm having a problem passing system types as a value to Type parameters in Silverlight. Is this some kind of known problem? Is it possible at all?

In details:
In my control I have dependency property of type `Type`. And there is a problem with passing types from `System` namespace, like `int(Int32)`, `string(String)`, `Guid`, `decimal(Decimal)`, `bool(Boolean)`. In these cases the depencency property receives `null` value (depencency property default value is set to some non-null value, so I see in OnPropertyChanged event that `null` is passed). For other types it works without problems.

Here is the code of my dependency property:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty SomeTypeProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "SomeType", typeof(Type), typeof(Control1), new PropertyMetadata(typeof(EmptyType), OnSomeTypePropertyChanged));
public Type SomeType
{
    get { return (Type)GetValue(SomeTypeProperty); }
    set { SetValue(SomeTypeProperty, value); }
}
```

And the control's usage:

```
xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
[...]
<sl1:Control1 SomeType="sys:Boolean" />
```

**What's interesting - it works in XAML designer in Visual Studio.** I know this by displaying the property value, so the passed Type, in my `Control1` control's content. But in Silverlight runtime environment it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why this is happening... However, here's a workaround..

1. Create the following class:

   ```
   public class TypeOfRes
   {
       public object Object { get; set; }

       public Type TypeOf
       {
           get { return Object == null ? null : Object.GetType(); }
       }
   }
   ```
2. Create the following resource in your page:

   ```
   <local:TypeOfRes x:Key="booleanRes">
       <local:TypeOfRes.Object>
           <sys:Boolean>True</sys:Boolean>
       </local:TypeOfRes.Object>
   </local:TypeOfRes>
   ```
3. Reference the resource in your property:

   ```
   <local:SilverlightControl1 MyType="{Binding Source={StaticResource booleanRes},Path=TypeOf}"/>
   ```

Comment: I know there are a few workarounds for this, including declaration of resources for every type I'd like to use, however I'm just curious why is this happening? And is it possible to do in nice, clean way - so without parsing Types from their names, treating separately every problematic type etc.